# Integration on Discontinuous Functions (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

I cannot tell if I am overthinking this. I am trying to answer the following question:

Determine for what values of $x\in\mathbb R$ that $F'(x)$ exists if $f(x)=$ \begin{cases} 
      1 & \text{if }x=1 \\
      0 & \text{if }x\neq1 
   \end{cases}

The way I'm reasoning through it, I have that
$F(x)=$ \begin{cases} 
      \int_1^11\text{ dt}=0 &   \text{if }x=1\\
      \int_1^x0\text{ dt}=0 & \text{if }x\neq1
   \end{cases}
So $F(x)=0$ and thus $F'(1)\neq f(1)$ so $F'(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: How is $F$ related to $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. The function $F$ is differentiable everywhere and, for each number $x$, $F'(x)=0$. The fact that $F'(1)\ne f(1)$ changes nothing.

Comment: I thought by FTC, $F'(x)=f(x)$, but I guess that is only true if $f(x)$ is continuous

Comment: Yes, continuity is important here.